# Can you use request scoped @Context variables in a singleton ContextResolver in JAX-RS?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey 1.13 with Spring.  I've got a ContextResolver defined like so:

```
@Provider
public class ThemeSourceContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ThemeSource> {

    @Context private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public ThemeSource getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return new DefaultThemeSource(request);
    }
}


<bean id="themeSourceContextResolver" scope="singleton" class="com.example.ThemeSourceContextResolver" />
```

Is the above valid?  Specifically, is it "legal" (or does it make sense) to use the `@Context private HttpServletRequest request` in a ContextResolver?  Since the ContextResolver is a singleton, does Jersey/JAX-RS do some threadlocal proxy magic or something to allow it to have access to the HttpServletRequest of every request?

Answer (score 0):

It's not valid. `@Context` is injected only into JAX-RS resources. `ContextResolver<?>` has nothing to do with request context, mostly because it's a singleton, as you said.

Comment: I've used `ContextResolver<T>` in Jersey 1.19 to chain providers and pass values between them. It doesn't seem to work in 2.x though.

Answer (score 0):

To update this answer for Jersey 2.14:

The answer is now "sometimes".  Jersey does indeed do proxy magic for specific @Context variables, namely HttpHeaders, Request, UriInfo and SecurityContext.  Your specific case, HttpServletRequest, is *not* supported.

See https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2578.