# Jersey 2 per-request @Context injection

Tags: dependency-injection, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

#### Overview

In Jersey 2, can I inject a custom, request-specific value into my resource?  Specifically, I would like to inject a `MyThing` which can be derived from my custom security context `MySecurityContext`.  I would like to inject `MyThing` directly to make the code clean.

Is there any way to do this?  According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13736627/4540) it can't be done using a `ContextResolver` although [this article](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/12/injecting-request-scoped-objects-into.html) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286400/4540) suggest it might be possible.

#### What Works

Using an auth filter, I am able to set my custom security context using code like this:

```
@Provider
public class HttpTokenAuthFilter implements IComposableJaxRsAuthFilter {

   @Override
   public boolean doAuth(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws WebApplicationException {
       // error handling omitted
       requestContext.setSecurityContext(MySecurityContext.fromHeaders(requestContext));
   }
}
```

... and then in my resource I can pull a value from it:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class MyResource {
    @Context 
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Get
    public String doGetFoo() {
       MyThing myThing = ((MySecurityContext)securityContext).getThing();
       // use myThing to produce a result
    }
```

#### Where I'm Stuck

... however, since this is going to be repeated a lot, I would much rather just write:

```
    @Context
    private MyThing myThing;
```

I tried defining a `ContextResolver`.  I see it getting constructed, but I never see it getting invoked, so I have not yet tried any of the techniques linked above.  Is this even the correct class to be using?

```
@Provider
public class MyThingResolver implements ContextResolver<MyThing> {

    public MyThingResolver() {
        System.out.println("ctor");
    }

    @Override
    public MyThing getContext(Class type) {
        System.out.println("getContext");

        if (type.equals(MyThing.class)) {
           return new MyThing(); // TODO: SHOULD ACTUALLY USE CURRENT MySession
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Almost the solution

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27666797/4540) and the refinements specified at [this followup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30871950/4540), it's *almost* possible to accomplish the injection using a `Factory`.  The only caveat is, you must inject `MyThing` via a `Provider`, otherwise it's going to get created (with the *default* `SecurityContext`) before the filter runs and swaps in the `MySecurityContext`.

The factory code looks like this:

```
public class MyThingFactory implements Factory<MyThing> {

    @Context
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Override
    public MyThing provide() {
        return ((MySecurityContext)securityContext).getThing();
    }

    @Override
        public void dispose(MyThing session) {
    }
}
```

The resource can then inject it like this:

```
@Context
private Provider<MyThing> myThingProvider;
```

... and consume it like this:

```
MyThing myThing = myThingProvider.get();
// use myThing
```

The factory registration in the `AbstractBinder` looks like this:

```
this.bindFactory(MyThingFactory.class) //
    .to(MyThing.class) //
    .in(RequestScoped.class);
```

#### (Edit) Proxies to the Rescue!

Per the comment from @peeskillet, it is possible to get rid of the `Provider` by proxying `MyThing`.  (Per @ jwells131313, `MyThing` must therefore be an interface or a proxy-able class.)

The binding then looks like this:

```
this.bindFactory(MyThingFactory.class) //
    .to(MyThing.class) //
    .proxy(true) //
    .in(RequestScoped.class);
```

and injection finally works as desired:

```
@Context
private MyThing myThing;
```

Comment: Another option, without the Provider, is to make MyThing a proxy. I think it needs to be an interface though. `.to(MyThing.class).proxy(true).proxyForSameScope(true)`. You might be able to leave off the last call. That might be the default value.

Comment: It doesn't *need* to be an interface to proxy it but if it is a class it'll need to follow the standard rules for proxies, like not be final and have a zero-arg constructor

Comment: Injecting SecurityContext as shown above does not appear to work - it injects a proxy (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487860/jax-rs-custom-securitycontext-has-unexpected-type-when-injected-into-resource-m ).  Did you actually get the above working?  If how, what was your magic for getting access to your custom MySecurityContext in the MyThingFactory?

Comment: @KevinDay - yeah, it was working when I posted.  But unfortunately it's been a long time since then and I don't remember the details any more.

Comment: Just in case anyone is trying it, Jersey doesn't provide access to the custom SecurityContext anymore.  The solution is to push MyThing into the context as a property (you can use anything for the property name): context.setProperty(MyThing.class.getName(), myThing);  then retrieve it in the factory (instead of using the SecurityContext):  MyThing myThing = (MyThing)requestContext.getProperty(MyThing.class.getName());